# Restrict privileges for ssh user login to php script

Tags: linux, ssh, user-management, permissions

I'm needing to work out a way of restricting a user (ssh login on ubuntu 10.04) to **only** be allowed to do the following:

- Upload txt files only (through SCP or SFTP)
- Execute the php command "php
  somefile.php"

Is this feasible?

Comment: Can `somefile.php` be different files or it it really fixed as `somefile.php` ?

Comment: @lain - That depends. If I can limit SCP uploads to only txt files, then restricting the php command to only certain scripts isn't as important. What I'm trying to stop is uploading and then executing a php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the users shell (in `/etc/passwd`) to a custom shell...

Simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash
php somefile.php    # You might need to give the full path to the php-bin.
bash -r -c read
```

Save it in `/bin`, add it to `/etc/shells` and make it runnable. The user can still use SCP and SFTP, but when he tries to open a shell, the php will run. If he enters, the shell will close.

Comment: How does this actually effect a certain user? I'm fairly new with these things. I only want to limit a `certainuser`. 
Do I need to add your script to the /etc/passwd file? But won't that then effect all users?

Comment: In the /etc/passwd you have some options for every user. One of them is their shell, you would need to change it for the user you want to. You would save this in /bin/myawesomeshell. Or if you want to do it via a command, you could use `usermod` ex: `usermod -s /bin/myawesomeshell myuser`

Comment: @TiZon - so for example I have this `someuser:x:5002:5002::/home/someuser:/bin/sh` and the `/bin/sh` is the shell, right? And I change that to mysawsomeshell ? Oh, perhaps usermod would be easiser

Comment: Yes, usermod would be easier. `/bin/sh`is indeed the shell.

Comment: @TiZon - Great! It's working wonderfully now. What are the possibilities with shells? I guess I'll ask Google, but this has been a great help.

Comment: Actually, a shell is a CLI (Command Line Interpreter). They come in man flavors (Bash, ...). The example above is based upon Bash. They explain it nicely here: http://linux.about.com/od/linux101/a/desktop11.htm

Comment: Does this prevent the user from doing something like "ssh user@emmaneuls.box 'rm -f *'"?

Comment: Yep. Nothing you type or pass in the arguments can be executed if the shell of the user `user` is `/bin/myawesomeshell` (or whatever you named it.)

Comment: @TiZon - After some testing, this isn't allowing me to use php_ssh2 to upload files via SCP. So it's not going to let me do what I need...

Comment: Accepted this answer as the most helpful, even though it doesn't solve my actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to serve the php script over a web server, and offer a text file upload through the same site.  That way you can have incredibly fine control over what's allowed and what's not.

Comment: Yes, that would. But impossible in my situation.